# How to show images related to ID in a database?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript-vue

I have searching bar in vue.js/native that provides a preview list of images from a database matching a given keyword. What I want to achieve is that, after clicking on one of the preview images, that image is displayed. So far I can only get the same image for all the previewed images by typing its url. The url is the same for each image with the only distinction of a unique ID (for example https://myimagedatabase.com/cases/getImage.php?id=1, https://myimagedatabase.com/cases/getImage.php?id=2, https://myimagedatabase.com/cases/getImage.php?id=3 and so on)

So far I have tried it with:

```
 <Image src="https://myimagedatabase.com/cases/getImage.php?id=1/>
```

which returns the image, but of course the same for every item on my preview list.

Also tried:

```
<Image src="https://myimagedatabase.com/cases/getImage.php?id=" + result[i].myIDs />
```

(myIDS was previously defined. I know it is wrong but I believe the best way to do it should be something like writing the common part of the link and then adding the ID number related to the given ID).

I also tried setting the image as a variable, adding the unique ID number for each ID and showing it with document.write, but it did not work.

Thanks for your help and suggestions in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to see more context of  your ```<template>```.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question and there are many ways to achieve what you are wanting to do.

You might do something like the following:

```
<template>
...
    <Image v-for="image in result" :src="getImageSrc(image.myIDs)"/>
...
</template>

<script>
...
  methods: {
  ...
    getImageSrc: (id) => `https://myimagedatabase.com/cases/getImage.php?id=${id}`
  ...
  }
...
</script>
```

I see `result[i].myIDs`  in your code.

Make sure you are using `v-for` to iterate over template statements. Take a look at the [List Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) section of the Vue documentation for examples.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for your reply. Now I have another problem (sorry about it, I am new at this): I created another .vue file in which I wrote (or at least I tried to do so) the function that displays the image once one of the preview items is clicked.       This .vue file is imported to the main .vue, but the problem is that It does not recognise a variable that I defined in the main file. Do you know how to make a variable, previously defined on another file, callable from the secondary file? Thanks again